# The "hover" not work properly

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, web-frontend

I have a problem with div "transition"\"hover" at my project : 
[Comverese](http://moransh4.github.io/comverse/).

At the section "SUCCESS STORIES" . when you hover the div's , it go up this o.k ,but not stay up when you move the mouse in that div.

What is the problem?

```
.story1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 22rem;
    height: 12rem;
    z-index: 9;
    background: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    -webkit-transition:transform .6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:transform .6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:transform .6s ease-out;
    -o-transition:transform .6s ease-out;
    transition:transform .6s ease-out;
}

.story1:hover{
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -moz-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -ms-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -o-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    transform:translate(0px,-200px);
}
```

Comment: Give some gode. How have you implement it?

Comment: I add now the class i use. you can see at the chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your div is not hovered anymore after it translates. The div moved up, and you're now hovering the div below (namely the `.quote` div) -> the story div comes back down.

One way to fix this is to use a bit of javascript instead of solely relying upon CSS. Adding a specific class on mouseenter and removing it when you're leaving the div below.

Something like the following (note that the JavaScript is a bit simple and should be improved upon to work for every story).

CSS:

```
.story1.translated {
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -moz-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -ms-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -o-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    transform:translate(0px,-200px);
}
```

JS :

```
var story1 = document.getElementsByClassName("story1")[0];    
var blockquote = document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0];    
story1.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    story1.className += " translated";
}
blockquote.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    story1.className = story1.className.replace(" translated", "");
}
```

**Edit**

A pure CSS solution would be to move the `:hover` part to `.story` and style `.story1` accordingly when it occurs. As follow:

```
.story:hover .story1{
    -webkit-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -moz-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -ms-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    -o-transform:translate(0px,-200px);
    transform:translate(0px,-200px);
}
```

This seems to work just fine when I change it locally to try it on your site.
And the same change can be applied to `.float-icon:hover` as well. Changing it to  `.story-icon:hover .float-icon` works wonders

Comment: Thanks!! there is a way to use just in css3 to fix this instead of javascript?

Comment: Now that I think about it, there is indeed a css3 solution. See my edit